# Adding a blank line after print before asking user for new variables in a loop

Tags: python

I'm doing some simple python exercises in which the target is to ask user for a word and a number of times the word gets printed in a loop.
The problem is that the program doesn't print a blank line after it prints the user given variables.

I've tried all sorts of \n-configurations with no success.

My program is:

```py
def printer(a,b):
    i=0
    for i in range(0,b):  
        print(a)
while True:
    text=input("Give text: ")
    if text=="stop":
        print("Stopping.") ##This works fine
        break
    else:
        number=int(input("Give number: "))
        printer(text, number)
```

Now the wanted print is:

```
Give text: text
Give number: 2
text
text

Give text: text
Give number:
```

But instead it prints it without any blank lines:

```
Give text: text
Give number: 2
text
text
Give text: text
Give number:
```

As I mentioned before I've tried all sorts of \n- and ""-configurations with no success.
How could I get the program to add a blank line at the end of the print before asking user for new variable.

Comment: just add a `print()` (empty) statement after the print loop.

Comment: Where have you tried putting the `\n` strings?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a print after the `for` loop:

```
def printer(a,b):
    i=0
    for i in range(0,b):  
        print(a)
    print()
while True:
    text=input("Give text: ")
    if text=="stop":
        print("Stopping.") ##This works fine
        break
    else:
        number=int(input("Give number: "))
        printer(text, number)
```